# Stripe Fabric iOS integration

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to set up Stripe using Fabric and my first step is of course to accept credit card information from a user. With the code I have below, the Submit button becomes enabled when it should but the app crashes when the button is clicked. The error message is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Stripe3.ViewController submitCard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe83740dbd0'"

I would greatly appreciate any insight!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate{

var paymentTextField: STPPaymentCardTextField! = nil
var submitButton: UIButton! = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    paymentTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField(frame: CGRectMake(15, 30, view.frame.width - 30, 44))
    paymentTextField.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(paymentTextField)
    submitButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
    submitButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 100, 100, 44)
    submitButton.isEnabled = false
    submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: UIControlState.normal)

    submitButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("submitCard:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(submitButton)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
    submitButton.isEnabled = textField.valid
}

@IBAction func submitCard(sender: AnyObject?) {
    // If you have your own form for getting credit card information, you can construct
    // your own STPCardParams from number, month, year, and CVV.
    let card = paymentTextField.card!

    STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: card) { token, error in
        guard let stripeToken = token else {
            NSLog("Error creating token: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
            return
        }

        // TODO: send the token to your server so it can create a charge
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome to Stripe", message: "Token created: \(stripeToken)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've properly linked the button storyboard's action to the right IBAction in the right UIViewController subclass. Sometimes it's just a matter of a Storyboard's scene/UI component copy/paste error.